# How to setup WF 4.0?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is WF 4.0 available for Visual Studio 2010 Express?  I installed VS2010 Express and I am confused about how to setup WF 4.0 templates and create a project.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know WF4 is not supported by the Express SKUs. However the WF4 runtime as wel as the WorkflowDesigner are part of the .NET framework so you can rehost the designer in your own applications, create workflows there and run them just fine. The biggest missing piece is IntelliSense in the designer. See [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx) blog post on how to rehost the designer in your own app.